# Why dont my calculations work?

Tags: c#, mouse, mousemove

This is more of a why doesn't this work question. I obviously must be missing something because I cannot for the life of me figure out why calculating the width and height values give me the same static value that I started with. But when I substitute hardcoded values it works just fine. So obviously my calculations are bad but I cannot seem to figure out why. Can anyone help? If you need more info please ask.

```
 if(objectList[selectedIndex].Selected == true)
 {
      //The width would be mouselocationx - objectlocationx
      //The height would be mouselocationy - objectlocationy
      //Off set the position so it doesnt snap to mouse location
      //WHY THE *%$!! DOESNT THIS WORK!!?!?!?!?!?!?
      //int width = e.X - objectList[selectedIndex].X;
      //int height = e.Y - objectList[selectedIndex].Y;
      //Why is this so hard??
      //Point location = objectList[selectedIndex].Location;
      //location.X = e.X - (e.X - objectList[selectedIndex].Location.X);
      //location.Y = e.Y - (e.Y - objectList[selectedIndex].Location.Y);
      objectList[selectedIndex].X = e.Location.X - 12;
      objectList[selectedIndex].Y = e.Location.Y - 12;
      objectLocationXLabel.Text = "OBJX: " + objectList[selectedIndex].X.ToString();
      objectLocationYLabel.Text = "OBJY: " + objectList[selectedIndex].Y.ToString();
      panel1.Invalidate();
   }
```

Comment: In your commented code you use `e.X` and `e.Y` but in your uncommented code you use `e.Location.X` and `e.Location.Y`

Comment: Have you tried the debugger? Set a breakpoint and see what is in e.Location.X, etc. Or do you have compile errors?

Comment: Yeah i dont think thats the problem. e.Location.X/Y and e.X/Y are the same value just a another way of obtaining it.

Comment: Yes but since its a mousemove event its hard to pinpoint the exact problem. It only executes the code once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you want to do. But there are at least two issues with your commented code:

```
location.X = e.X - (e.X - objectList[selectedIndex].Location.X);
```

is equivalent to

```
location.X = objectList[selectedIndex].Location.X;
```

`Point` is a value type. So when you do this:

```
Point location = objectList[selectedIndex].Location;
location.X = ...;
```

`location` is modified, but not `objectList[selectedIndex].Location`.

Edit in response to comment: I think you must determine the offset in the `MouseDown` event, store it in a member and use it in `MouseMove`.

Comment: Yeah sorry its hard to explain what im trying to accomplish. See im trying to off set the object location so it doesnt always snap to the mouse location. If that helps. I thought if i found the distance between the object.x/y locations and mouse.x/y locations i could use that to off set the object. But i guess i suck at math.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason i completely neglected trying this.